# What's going on with Angular's libraries? Are these redundant?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I just came back to Angular after a few years away. There are what appear to be redundant Material libraries. They have two conventions: "@angular/material" and "angular-material". There are "animations" and "animate", as well as "route" and "router".

Also, some sites suggest using "ng add x" while others suggest "npm install x".

Maybe this is totally normal, but I worry I fell into an outdated-docs trap.

Can any Angular experts out there help? Are these conflicting libs, or do they have important differences?

Thanks in advance!

Here are the dependencies in my brand new project:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~11.2.1",
    "@angular/cdk": "^11.2.1",
    "@angular/common": "~11.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~11.2.1",
    "@angular/core": "~11.2.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~11.2.1",
    "@angular/material": "^11.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~11.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~11.2.1",
    "@angular/router": "~11.2.1",
    "angular": "^1.8.2",
    "angular-animate": "^1.8.2",
    "angular-aria": "^1.8.2",
    "angular-material": "^1.2.2",
    "angular-messages": "^1.8.2",
    "angular-route": "^1.8.2",
    "angular-sanitize": "^1.8.2",
    "crypto-js": "^4.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.3"
  }
```

Comment: Seems like you are mixing up with Angular and AngularJS. All those `angular-*` v:1.8.2 are AngularJS

Comment: Ok, that would explain it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have angularJS (this is the v1 of angular) and Angular "@angular/core": "~11.2.1" (lastest version of angular) in this project.

You need to remove this if you want to work angular:

```
  "angular": "^1.8.2"
  "angular-animate": "^1.8.2",
  "angular-aria": "^1.8.2",
  "angular-material": "^1.2.2",
  "angular-messages": "^1.8.2",
  "angular-route": "^1.8.2",
  "angular-sanitize": "^1.8.2",
```

Or if you want to work with angularJS remove:

```
    "@angular/animations": "~11.2.1",
    "@angular/cdk": "^11.2.1",
    "@angular/common": "~11.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~11.2.1",
    "@angular/core": "~11.2.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~11.2.1",
    "@angular/material": "^11.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~11.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~11.2.1",
    "@angular/router": "~11.2.1"
```

Additional its good idea if you install angular CLI to create applications that already works and follow the best practices. From the web [cli.angular.io](https://cli.angular.io/) You can run:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
ng new my-dream-app
cd my-dream-app
ng serve
```

Have nice day!

Comment: Thanks for the details! My problem came after the Angular CLI setup (which is great, btw). I went looking for component libraries, and found myself on the Material site for AngularJS. Then I tried to add those components, and yada yada. That documentation could be more blatantly labelled 'This is old!', but it was my own fault.